# Check to see if polar coordinates are correct

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

This is an extension of a question I asked earlier, but with some slight changes to it. We have $x^2+y^2\leqslant2x+2y$ as a $2D$ region and we need to solve $\int\int{y\,dA}$

To see what this is I did the following:

$x^2+y^2-2x-2y$

$(x^2-2x)+(y^2-2y)$

$(x^2-2x+1)+(y^2-2y+1)$

$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 \leqslant 1^2$

So this has a center at (1,1) and a radius of 1 in the first and second quadrant of the disk. Therefore, my new limits of integration look like:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\cos\theta+2\sin\theta} r^2\sin\theta \,dr\,d\theta$$

Is this correct? I believe it's $\pi$ and not $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $d\theta$, but I want to make sure the answer so far is fine.

Comment: What change of variables do you make?

Comment: Asuming you mean what I think you do...that would be x=rcos(theta), y=rsin(theta), and dA=rdrd(theta). Also...I just noticed...a radius of 1 puts it squarely in the first quadrant...so maybe this is pi/2 after all as a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not correct. In the work that you showed, three lines don't even have right-hand sides, and that's very suspicious. Even worse, that lead to an actual mistake: when you finally decided to write a right-hand side as "$\color{red}{\le1^2}$" — where did that $\color{red}{1^2}$ come from? It's actually wrong there. While your work on the left-hand side is correct, you have to work with the **entire inequality** to get a correct result. This shape is indeed a disk (filled circle) centered at $(1,1)$, but its radius is **NOT** $\color{red}{1}$.

You can also check your answer with some special points. It's easy to see that the origin $(0,0)$ satisfies the equation $x^2+y^2=2x+2y$, so it has to lie on the boundary of the given region; but it doesn't lie on the circumference of your circle centered at $(1,1)$ of radius $1$, so this is not the right circle.

As for the integral in polar coordinates that you need to obtain: your integrand $\color{green}{r^2\sin\theta}$ is correct, and your limits of integration for $r$, viz. $\color{green}{0}$ and $\color{green}{2\cos\theta+2\sin\theta}$, are also correct. But both limits of integration for $\theta$, viz. $\color{red}{0}$ and $\color{red}{\pi}$, are wrong because of the mistake explained above.

Comment: Sorry, it was just my shorthand. That's probably why it's wrong,lol. I Didn't mean for it to seem suspicious. You're right, I forgot to add what I did on the left, to the right side as well. If I do that, the radius becomes sqrt(2) since it's in the form (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 <= 2, right?

Comment: @ARow: Yes, that's correct now! Draw the circle to help yourself see the correct limits of integration for $\theta$.

Comment: I guess I just have a problem seeing where theta ranges. I graphed it on desmos just to get a visual, and a portion of the circle is in the second half of the graph, so I guess the top range of the integral is 2pi since you would need 2pi revolutions to cover the circle. But if you don't start at theta=0 for the bottom, where does it start?

Comment: @ARow: See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gdq33p2tsb. The line $y=-x$ is tangent to this circle at the origin. So $\theta$ ranges, revolving counterclockwise, from its fourth-quadrant direction (the ray $\theta=\cdots$) to its second-quadrant direction (the ray $\theta=\cdots$).

Comment: If I'm following you correctly the ranges you're hinting to are 2pi and pi. That's the only way I see it rotate the rest of the surface area of the circle.

Comment: @ARow: No, you're not following correctly. What is the polar angle corresponding to the direction of the ray $y=-x$ that goes into the fourth quadrant? It's neither $\theta=\pi$ nor $\theta=2\pi$, both of which lie on the line $y=0$.

Comment: Since y=-x does a completely angled line down the coordinate plane, I'm guessing that's 7pi/4

Comment: @ARow: Better. But $-\pi/4$ would work even better. Now, what's the angle for its second-quadrant ray? (After you answer this question the way I think you're going to, you should realize why $-\pi/4$ is a better choice than $7\pi/4$.)

Comment: Well, the companion of 7pi/4 is 3pi/4 in the second quadrant. Where did -pi/4 come from though?

Comment: @ARow: $\theta=-\pi/4$ is coterminal to $\theta=7\pi/4$, so geometrically they define the same ray. I expected that you will choose $\theta=3\pi/4$ for the second quadrant ray, and it's perfectly fine. Now, the thing is that from the lower limit of integration to the upper limit of integration the numerical values of $\theta$ should be increasing while the rays rotate counterclockwise. But if you start with $\theta=7\pi/4$ and keep **increasing** $\theta$ by rotating it counterclockwise, you can **NOT** possibly arrive at $\theta=3\pi/4$, which is a **smaller** number.

Comment: @ARow: (continued) Instead, by the time you arrive at that ray in the second quadrant, the value of the polar angle will be $\theta=11\pi/4$. And there's nothing wrong with that, by the way! You can choose $-\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$ as your limits of integration, or you can choose $7\pi/4$ and $11\pi/4$ as your limits of integration -- either way is fine. You do have choices, but it's important that they match by actually increasing while rotating counterclockwise.

Comment: I'm going to have to study coterminal angles more, lol. Seems like it would make things easier. Still, with the angles I gave, yes, in terms of the integral a= 3pi/4 and b (top)=7pi/4 since it is the bigger value.

Comment: In any event, thanks for sticking with it :) I know that was a while. I learned a lot. I'll mark your answer in a minute once I finish this.

Comment: @ARow: If you set up $a=3\pi/4$ as the lower limit and $b=7\pi/4$ as the upper limit, it will be wrong too, because rotating counterclockwise you will be going thru the other halfplane (the lower one on the picture), which is not where the circle is.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part xD. I just realize I could edit this lol. Should have been a= 7pi/4 and b= 11pi/4

Answer (score 1):

There's something thing wrong here, for one thing, the radius of the circle centered at $(1,1)$ has a radius of $\sqrt{2}$. I believe that I *see* the solution to this problem so that you can check your integral later. The integral you are calculating is related to the centroid of the circle, which is clearly at the center of the circle, i.e. $(1,1)$. Now, the centroid is given by

$$R_y=\frac{\int\!\!\!\int y~dA}{\int\!\!\!\int dA}=\frac{1}{A}\int\!\!\!\int y~dA$$

So, clearly

$$\int\!\!\!\int y~dA=R_yA=R_y\pi r^2=2\pi$$

since $R_y=1$ and $r=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: @zipirovich Thanks, I cannot imagine a nicer compliment.